# Windows Phone Development data from website

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I was thinking of creating a project which requires data from different sites so that I could do a comparison such as price and features, I will be building a Windows Phone application, and wanted to know how to get data from the sites.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the websites you are using have APIs then you should register your application with them to get the access token and use it to get the data which might be sent to you as XML or JSON then you can parse the response and present the data to the user.

If the websites don't have APIs, then the only way is to use [Web Scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Web_scraping) which involves downloading the page HTML and then parsing it using a library like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Great, but I am new to Windows Phone Development. So I was able to get clear about Web APIs that websites provide through an access token, and they return the results in JSON and XMl, and they recommend JSON, what I wanted to know is could you give me an small example of JSON code and C# code to display values such as Product name and Price.

Comment: Well, since all you will doing with JSON is to parse it to get data, i recommend downloading JSON.NET from [link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and then on that same website, they have put great documentation for how to use it. It is very easy.